# Запуск socket.io сервера через браузер

Tags: node.js, сервер, socket.io

уважаемые.

Занимаюсь созданием игры на node.js / socket.io.

Просмотрел в интернете много информации, но так и не получилось найти ответ на свой вопрос.

Игра уже стоит на сервере, и запускается через команду `node index` в консоле сервера.

Вопрос заключается в следующем:
Можно ли как-то создать страницу для админа с кнопками "Включить" и "Выключить" сервер?
Вот так у меня сейчас выглядет index.js

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

const mysql = require('mysql2');

let dateFormat = require('dateformat');
let crypto = require('crypto');
let fs = require('fs');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/ssl')
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'))

let server = require('https').createServer(opts, app);
server.listen(4000, function(){
})

io.attach(server);

app.get('/', function (request, respons) { // Подключение основного файла
  respons.sendFile(__dirname + 'index.php');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите на такой пример

```
index.js

const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<form action="/exit" method="post"> <button name="exit" value="send">Exit</button> </form>')
})

const server = app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server ready'))

app.post('/exit', (req, res) => {
  res.send('closed')
  console.log('Process terminating')
  process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGTERM')
})
```

**npm init**

**npm install express**

**node index.js**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

открываем браузер localhost:3000

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

жмем Exit
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

localhost:3000/exit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути посылаете `fetch('/exit')` запрос из клиента и всё.

Comment: Здравствуйте, дополнил вопрос. 
А не могли бы вы показать как это бы происходило со стороны страницы клиента. Что подключается и какой запрос посылается после нажатия на кнопку

Comment: Вот вы в начале в консоли прописали ```node index.js``` а можно это как то сделать так же кнопкой как и exit?

Comment: Увы нет. Этот запрос должено что-то обработать. Вы можете указать работающему приложению о завершении. Чтоб запустить его удалено нужна другая программа которая сделает это